# Communicating Raspberry Pi with cloudfoundry

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, cloud-foundry, socket.io

I have written a Node.js socket.io routine which will be called by a python socket io routine from my raspberry pi. It will communicate both ways. At the moment when I run these two routines on localhost it works fine. However when I deploy the server application to cloudfoundry and change the SocketIO connection link to cloudfoundry it does not work. Below is the client python

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

def on_updatepi_response(*args):
    print 'updatepi'

def on_receivepi_response(*args):
    print 'receiveepi'    

with SocketIO('raspinode-server.cloudfoundry.com', 8080) as socketIO:
    socketIO.on('receivepi', on_receivepi_response)
    socketIO.on('updatepi', on_updatepi_response)
    socketIO.emit('sendrabbit','testdata')
    socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

I know cloudfoundry can be a bit strange as my first idea was to use rabbitmq but it is tied to the VCAP_SERVICES idea. However I did not think such a restriction would be there on a Node.js page.

Let me know if there is anything wrong with the above code and if not how can i get my external pi to send reading to my cloud app ?

Server Code is listed below though it is not relevant. It responds on localhost...I know the rabbitmq code is not hooked up yet

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var amqp = require('amqp');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

function rabbitUrl() {
    if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
        conf = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
        return conf['rabbitmq-2.4'][0].credentials.url;
    }
    else {
        return "amqp://localhost";
    }
}

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;

var messages = [];

function setup() {
    var exchange = conn.exchange('cf-demo', {'type':'fanout', durable:false}, function(){
        var queue = conn.queue('', {durable:false, exclusive:true},

            function() {
                queue.subscribe(function(msg) {
                    messages.push(htmlEscape(msg.body));
                    if (messages.length > 10) {
                        messages.shift();
                    }
                });
                queue.bind(exchange.name, '');
            }); 
            queue.on('queueBindOk', function() {httpServer(exchange);});
    });
}


server.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    // when the client emits sendrabbit, this listens
    socket.on('sendrabbit', function(data)
    {

        // we tell the client to execute updatepi with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.emit('updatepi', socket.username, data)
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function()
    {
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatepi', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that your server should listen on the port Cloud Foundry assigns it (available in an env var).  You can't assume it will be 8080.  Then the client talks to raspinode-server.cloudfoundry.com (no port) and Cloud Foundry routes it to the correct place.